# how can i resolve this error when i use gulp pack my js files

Tags: reactjs, gulp

events.js:160
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h5cp.png)
[image]

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var shim = require('browserify-shim');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

var uglify = require('gulp-uglify')

gulp.task('script:build', function() {
    browserify('app/main.js')
       .transform(babelify, {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
       })
       .transform(shim)
       .bundle()
       .pipe(source('bundle.js').om('error',function (e) {
        console.log(e);
       }))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

});

gulp.task('default', ['script:build']);
```

Comment: We can't debug a gulpfile error without the source for said gulpfile.

Comment: I have update my gulpfile

Comment: You've got a typo there. `.om('error')` instead of `.on('error')`.

Comment: but  i got this error   events.js:160 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�'   i can't find the reason